# Getting guild id [Discord.py] [json]

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, when my bot is offline and someone adds it in their server i'm getting a key error after the bot is again up because can't find the ID in the json file, so the problem i need to fix somehow, when the bot is again online to take the guild ID and put inside the json. someone told me to do a  `try except` thing but i don't understand how to get the guild id and put in the json after the bot goes online
here is the code, i feel like it's pretty simple to do it but right now i literally don't get it

````
    with open('prefixes.json' , 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

 
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)



@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = 's!'

    with open('prefixes.json' , 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent = 4 )

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild) :
    with open('prefixes.json' , 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefixes.json' , 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent = 4 )```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
try:
   # get prefix, and then return it
   with open('prefixes.json' , 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

 
        return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

except KeyError: # if the code above failed and raise KeyError code below will executed
   #insert the data to json, and the return the default prefix
   with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] = 's!'

    with open('prefixes.json' , 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent = 4 )
    return "s!" # or you can repeat the process of getting the prefix
```

Comment: i tried that and gives me another errors,   ` line 28, in get_prefix
    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = 's!'
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'id'` and  :  line 21, in get_prefix
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
KeyError: ' - '

Comment: @Ares edited, I missed something. Sorry for that. Still get any error?

Comment: Now it is working fine, thank you, i really had a pretty hard time trying to fix it